# Problem with installing Anki 2.0.33 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, anki

After installing Anki on my Ubuntu, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/anki", line 7, in <module>
    import aqt   File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *   File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 7, in <module>
    from anki.utils import isWin, isMac   File "/usr/share/anki/anki/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anki.storage import Collection   File "/usr/share/anki/anki/storage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from anki.db import DB   File "/usr/share/anki/anki/db.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

Installation via apt-get and software center gives the same result. 
What should I do to resolve that issue?